# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_80.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors

**Platform: Windows 10, Visual Studio VC142**

I'm using **Boost 1.80.0** in my project. **I've built Boost and been using modules such as Container without issue**, however I tried to use Boost.Serialization and I get a link error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_80.lib'`

When checking the directory full of .lib files, I see similar files but nothing with `-mt-s-x64`:

[image: Windows File Explorer inside C:/code/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib]

**I am seeking insight on why the linker is looking for this lib which the setup process (bootstrap, build) does not emit.**

My pre-compile command:

```
@call cl.exe ^
/c ^
/Ycstdafx.hpp ^
src/stdafx.cpp ^
/Yustdafx.hpp ^
/Fo:obj_debug\ ^
/Fe:dist\swan_debug.exe ^
/Fd:dist\vc140_debug.pdb ^
/I"C:/code/glfw" ^
/I"C:/code/boost_1_80_0" ^
/std:c++20 ^
/W4 ^
/EHsc ^
/MP ^
/MT ^
/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ^
/Zi ^
/link ^
/DEBUG:FULL ^
/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD ^
/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT ^
/LIBPATH:"C:/code/glfw" ^
/LIBPATH:"C:/code/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib" ^
glfw3.lib ^
opengl32.lib ^
gdi32.lib ^
shell32.lib ^
kernel32.lib ^
msvcrt.lib ^
ole32.lib ^
shlwapi.lib ^
Pathcch.lib
```

My main compile command:

```
@call cl.exe ^
src/all_in_one.cpp ^
obj_debug/imgui_demo.obj ^
obj_debug/imgui_draw.obj ^
obj_debug/imgui_impl_glfw.obj ^
obj_debug/imgui_impl_opengl3.obj ^
obj_debug/imgui_tables.obj ^
obj_debug/imgui_widgets.obj ^
obj_debug/imgui.obj ^
obj_debug/stb_image.obj ^
obj_debug/stdafx.obj ^
/Fo:obj_debug\ ^
/Fe:dist\swan_debug.exe ^
/Fd:dist\vc140_debug.pdb ^
/Yustdafx.hpp ^
/I"C:/code/glfw" ^
/I"C:/code/boost_1_80_0" ^
/std:c++20 ^
/nologo ^
/W4 ^
/EHsc ^
/MP ^
/MT ^
/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ^
/Zi ^
/link ^
/NATVIS:swan.natvis ^
/DEBUG:FULL ^
/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD ^
/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT ^
/LIBPATH:"C:/code/glfw" ^
/LIBPATH:"C:/code/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib" ^
glfw3.lib ^
opengl32.lib ^
gdi32.lib ^
shell32.lib ^
kernel32.lib ^
msvcrt.lib ^
ole32.lib ^
shlwapi.lib ^
Pathcch.lib ^
Dbghelp.lib
```

Compiler output:

```
all_in_one.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30148.0    
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:dist\swan_debug.exe
/debug
/NATVIS:swan.natvis
/DEBUG:FULL
/NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRTD
/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT
/LIBPATH:C:/code/glfw
/LIBPATH:C:/code/boost_1_80_0/stage/lib
glfw3.lib
opengl32.lib
gdi32.lib
shell32.lib
kernel32.lib
msvcrt.lib
ole32.lib
shlwapi.lib
Pathcch.lib
Dbghelp.lib
obj_debug\all_in_one.obj
obj_debug/imgui_demo.obj
obj_debug/imgui_draw.obj
obj_debug/imgui_impl_glfw.obj
obj_debug/imgui_impl_opengl3.obj
obj_debug/imgui_tables.obj 
obj_debug/imgui_widgets.obj
obj_debug/imgui.obj
obj_debug/stb_image.obj
obj_debug/stdafx.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_80.lib'
```

Comment: Read carefully about Boost on [Windows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).  Note that the `-s` means "link statically", and that library is being asked for — but that library has not been (pre-) built yet.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you do not have the file "libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_80.lib" in the library path you have provided. The usual way I look for missing .lib or .dll files is using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/). Search for the .lib file using this app in you system and if you find it, put it in your library search path.

Answer (score 1):

Not all boost modules need a library (some are header only) which is why you've been able to use boost up 'til now.

The [name of the missing library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) indicates that it is a static library rather than an import library linking to a DLL.

This gives you one way to resolve the problem. If you change your project to link with the C/C++ runtimes dynamically then boost will also switch to dynamic linking. Use the /MD option not the /MT option, IIRC it's under C/C++/Code Generation in Project Properties.

But if you don't want to do that then you have to build a static version of the boost libraries. Instructions for doing that are [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source).

Comment: They've already got static libraries, it's the static runtime that they're missing

Comment: @AlanBirtles `cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_80.lib'` seems pretty clear to me. Am I missing something? Both the dupes you found say exactly the same thing that I said.

Comment: you said `The name of the missing library indicates that it is a static library rather than an import library linking to a DLL`, the installed libraries start with `lib` so are already static libraries, the issue is that they're linked to the msvc dlls not the static msvc runtime

Comment: @AlanBirtles Right, got it. I had that confused.